# How to show more than 1 data in php array after doing min and max

Tags: php

I'm doing my homework and I can't find the solution to displaying more than one result in array after doing min and max syntax

my teacher said that I should use `min` and `max` to show more than 1 result

```
$temperatures = [78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73];
$max = max($temperatures);
$min = min($temperatures);
```

The final result should be:

> average of the temperatures : 70.6
>   the five lowest temperature lists : 60, 62, 63, 63, 64
>   the five highest temperature lists : 76, 78, 79, 81, 85

Comment: really? I'd say it's much better to simply sort the array and then split it..

Comment: There is no 81 in your array

Comment: that's my teacher's question, and I just asking how to displaying more than 1 result when using min and max tag, is it possible ?

Comment: @Horakhty https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php I'm not sure how possible that actually is without chunking the array, which is just overkill ..

Comment: You can use `for` loop . [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents on it:

```
$temperatures = [78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73];

# simply sum the elements then divide by count
$avg = (array_sum($temperatures) / count($temperatures));

# sort arr low -> high
sort($temperatures);
# make els unique
$temperatures = array_unique($temperatures);

$min = array_slice($temperatures, 0, 5); # get first 5 in array
$max = array_slice($temperatures, -5); # get last 5 in array

echo '<pre>'. print_r($avg, 1) .'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'. print_r($min, 1) .'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'. print_r($max, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Comment: I don't think `array_unique` is required.. temp can could be same.

Comment: @danish-khan-I comment out the array_unique, and see output - it shows dupe vals :)

Comment: @treyBake its good to have array_unique to check duplicate - nice :)